# mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to do change my document root using rewrite rules in my .htaccess file, and also redirect all requests to `index.php` except static resources

In other words:

1. if a file with the path prepended with `www` exists (i.e. `www/{%request_uri}`):
   `http://domain.com/css/main.css` should be rewritten to `http://domain.com/www/css/main.css`
2. if that file does not exist, redirect to the app main entry point `www/index.php`:
   e.g.

   `http://domain.com` should be rewritten to `http://domain.com/www/index.php`

   `http://domain.com/hello` should be rewritten to `http://domain.com/www/index.php/hello`

   `http://domain.com/hello?a=1` should be rewritten to `http://domain.com/www/index.php/hello?a=1`

I tried variations, however either it gives us 500 internal server error, or infinite loop. Here is one that gives 500 internal server error:

```
# try to find it in www/
RewriteCond {%DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond {%DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) www/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) www/index.php/$1 [L]
```

This one also:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www/
RewriteRule (.*) /www/$1

RewriteCond {%REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule www/(.*) /www/index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this need to be done with a mod rewrite or could it be done with PHP? If you're not wanting the option of doing it in PHP then please remove the php tag, as it's totally irrelevant.

Comment: I have removed the php tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I made a stupid mistake! The `%` sign should be outside of the `{}` bracket!

This can be done in one .htaccess in root dir:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^www/(.*)$ www/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's impossible with a single `.htaccess` but it's possible with two.

You need one in your root directory, `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# We don't want infinite rewriting.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [L]
```

And another in your www directory, `/www/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /www

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I figured it out myself. Thanks anyways!